# Which Winter Olympic sports gather the highest TV viewership?

Tags: trivia, olympics, media

**Which Winter Olympic sports gather the highest TV viewership?**

This question is partly based on the assumption that Norway, which is where I'm from, overestimates cross-country skiing as a major sport.

Comment: In the Netherlands we consider speed skating as a major sport :) I think a good measure would be the historical diversity of countries with medalists.

Comment: Completely agree with your comments, I see now how this was a bad question. Regarding using "size", english is not my native language, I realize now it's a badly chosen word for this matter. And to narrow my question, it would be very interesting to see number of TV-viewvers for the different disciplines.

Comment: Okay. I see where you are coming from. I'll attempt to revise your question. Also, here is a link regarding US TV viewership from the 2010 Winter Olympics: http://www.nielsen.com/us/en/newswire/2010/skiing-tops-olympic-tv-viewership-while-hockey-scores-online.html

Answer (score -1):

This a link which I came upon recently.

http://www.thisisinsider.com/most-watched-winter-olympic-sport-in-every-country-2018-2

Comment: You should write part of the link which answer the question here, as link may get broken.